# Url launcher does not open with appbar

Tags: flutter

what i want is to get the top bar when I launch URL inappwebview, where it shows Done Mobile.twitter.com aA and refresh icon

[image]

So I've tried

```
await launchUrl(
Uri.parse(url),
mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
);
```

as well as  downgraded url_launcher and tried this

```
launch(url,
    forceWebView: true, forceSafariVC: true, enableJavaScript: true);
```

None seem to work,

[image]

I keep getting the website without the appbar with Done, refresh on top of it

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem when upgrading from using the deprecated **launch(url)** method to **launchUrl(uri)**.

All it needs is to pass the LaunchMode as below.

`launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication )`